# Why does Jackson ignore in-class annotations but respect mix-in annotations?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, polymorphism, swagger

I use the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` version `2.2.2` to generate Java classes for a REST API. The API uses polymorphism and Swagger provides corresponding annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type", 
  visible = true )
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat"),
  @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog") })

public class Pet{

  @JsonProperty("type")
  private String type = null;

  // getter and setters

}
```

Now I use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to parse the incoming JSON string. I use the Jackson that comes with the `1.5.2.RELEASE` of `spring-boot-starter-parent`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String body = "{ \"pet\": { \"type\": \"Dog\" } }";
Content content = mapper.readValue(body, Content.Class);
```

However, this fails. Jackson ignores the annotations and maps everything to `Pet` instead of `Dog`:

```
Dog dog = (Dog) content.getPet(); // -> ClassCastException
```

As a workaround, I added mix-in annotations that do nothing more than the original annotations. The only difference is that they reside in a separate class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type", 
  visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat"), 
  @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog")})

public class PetAnnotations {
}
```

Now this works:

```
// like above
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Pet.class, PetAnnotations.class);
Content content = mapper.readValue(body, Content.Class);
Dog dog = (Dog) content.getPet(); // -> works!
```

Any ideas why Jackson ignores the in-class annotations but respects the annotations I explicitly hand in as mix-ins?